# SQLALCHEMY problema con suma de campos

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, sum

tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT partediarioriego.fechaPartediarioriego,sum(partediariolote.solidoPartediariolote),
                        sum(partediariolote.liquidoPartediariolote)
                        FROM tecnoredDB.partediariolote
                        INNER JOIN partediarioriego
                        ON partediarioriego.idPartediarioriego = partediariolote.idPartediarioriego
                        WHERE idPlanta=5
                        GROUP BY partediarioriego.fechaPartediarioriego;
```

estoy tratando de hacer esta consulta por medio de alchemy,pero el resultado no se suma,esta es la consulta con la que estoy intentando.

```
db.session.query(Partediariolote,func.sum(Partediariolote.solidoPartediariolote).label('solido'),func.sum(Partediariolote.liquidoPartediariolote).label('liquido'),Partediarioriego).join(Partediarioriego, Partediarioriego.idPartediarioriego == Partediariolote.idPartediarioriego).filter(Partediarioriego.idPlanta == idplanta_session).filter(Partediarioriego.fechaPartediarioriego.between(desde,hasta)).group_by(Partediarioriego,Partediarioriego.fechaPartediarioriego).all()
```